# wordpress database select security

Tags: wordpress

I'm returning some data from custom table, but I'm not sure if is the code enough secured. Can you help me?

```
$page_title = get_the_title();    
$id = $wpdb->get_row('select id from table where name="'.htmlspecialchars($page_title).'"');
```

Comment: Why you think so that the code is not enough secured ? Describe more specifically.

Comment: I read some article about $wpdb class and there was written something like I have to escape variables, but I don't know if htmlspecialchars function is enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you would match a title, usually when doing a search its better to use an id.

But this is what a custom query would look like to get a post id when the title matches the var. prepare does the proper escaping. See the first place prepare comes up here http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

```
global $wpdb;
$page_title = get_the_title();
$id = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare('SELECT id FROM ' . $wpdb->posts . ' WHERE post_title = %s', $post_title));
```

Or you could use WordPress's esc_sql() function on your var.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_sql

But like I said, this query seems backwards. If you have get_the_title() you should also have the_ID() or get_the_ID() so the query is not needed. So it depends what you are trying to do.